# PHP include with parameter does not load page

Tags: php, parameters, include

I'm using PHP Version 5.3.28.  I'm trying to include a page using DOCUMENT_ROOT, but if I attach any parameters to the URL, nothing displays.

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mysiteDir/phpPage.php?data=string");
```

If I take away "?data=string" it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will clarify things for you - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

To cut it short, `include 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2';`, won't work because PHP looks for a file named `file.php?foo=1&bar=2` on the local filesystem. However, this only applies for local includes. If you use remote includes, such `http://www.example.com?r=g`, it will work.

Comment: Thank you. I never knew that.